# House pet vs farm animal

Tags: words

A friend posted a photo with capybara.

I want to ask if this is his pet or a farm animal.

How do I say this?

Should I use these words? 家畜, ペット

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly, at least for me, asking if a capybara is a pet is just too outrageous for anything to sound natural (although apparently, it is technically possible in Japan).

---

I guess normally people would say 飼ってるんですか to ask if it is a pet.

家畜 refers to animals kept for some sort of utilities - meat, agriculture etc. As far as I know, in Japan, capybaras are not used for any of these. Mostly they are in zoos, and animals in zoos are pragmatically neither ペット nor 家畜. They are just 動物.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't think of a capybara as 'livestock' in English either

Comment: Yeah, this is a strange dichotomy. Neither of the OP's English options would occur to me to ask.

Comment: @sundowner Thank you for the answer! Why is it outrageous? It’s the same as asking if a dog in a photo is someone’s pet. In case of capybara, everyone knows it’s just a joke and conversation starter.